# how to change Nginx source to support variable for special directive

Tags: nginx

I want change source of nginx to support variable for proxy_cache_valid directive like :

> `set $test 10m;  proxy_cache_valid 200 $test;`

when reading source of Nginx, I know this directive handler is

> `ngx_http_file_cache_valid_set_slot()`

and I should change this function, so I need to get variable value by

> `ngx_http_get_variable_index()`

to replace them with :

> `$test`

but this function not return value of

> $test

`

How do I solve this problem?